# Ajax trigger live and dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, live

let's say I have a code like that:

```
<div id="stuff<? echo $dynID; ?>" class="bla">
 <form id="myform<? echo $dynID; ?> " action="bla.php">
    <input name="iname<? echo $dynID; ?>" value="<? echo $row[1]; ?>">
 </form>
</div>

<div id="stuff<? echo $dynID; ?>" class="bla">
 <form id="myform<? echo $dynID; ?> " action="bla.php">
    <input name="iname<? echo $dynID; ?>" value="<? echo $row[1]; ?>">
 </form>
</div>

<div id="stuff<? echo $dynID; ?>" class="bla">
 <form id="myform<? echo $dynID; ?> " action="bla.php">
    <input name="iname<? echo $dynID; ?>" value="<? echo $row[1]; ?>">
 </form>
</div>
```

Many forms. In this example 3. (It could be more or less)

How can I trigger this form (to send ist with AJAX)? This form is live-AJAX generated content and have a dynamic ID. I did not now the specific ID of the form to trigger like:

```
$("#myform").submit(function(event) {
```

How, can I handle this?

Comment: do you have multiple form in your page that have dynamic id?

Comment: If you don't know the ID or at least some other means of identifying the target form you're always going to struggle.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple forms with a dynamic ID.

Answer (score 0):

We could use some more information to help further, for example, is the text in this form (any of it) unique when compared to other forms? You can target it by basically anything and even combine these conditions. For example, if the action attribute is unique you could always do something like this (untested):

```
//if the form id starts with 'myform', perform a function on submit
$("form[id^='myform']").submit(function(event) {
    //if that form's 'action' attribute is 'bla.php', then do something
    if($('form').attr('action', 'bla.php')){
        //your code here
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
Is this unique enough to snag it? I've made it rely on the div above it having an id that starts with 'stuff', that div must also have class 'bla' and the form attribute of 'action' must be 'bla.php'

```
$("div[id^='stuff'] form[id^='myform']").submit(function(event) {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass('bla')) {
        if($(this).attr('action', 'bla.php')){
            //your code here
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I edited the code in my question to show what is in the form.

Comment: The action go on bla.php an every form.

Comment: For what is it for: I loop through a Database and write out the rows. Let's say: I have 4 different forms with dynamic IDs. I need the form for an edit function.

Comment: I've edited my answer, but if every form is identical with the exemption of dynamic id ending, that would be a bit tougher.

Comment: The thing is: That "[id^='stuff']", "[id^='myform']" and "('action', 'bla.php')" ist true vor every form on the page.

Comment: I edit my code  (in my question) a little bit. To be more specific.

Comment: Are there any unique identifiers for anything on the page? If so, I suggest targeting your form by using the unique item for relevant targeting. If you find a unique item in your HTML and update your question I can help further. But as is with no unique Identifier in sight, it seems a bit more tricky. Even if the text used in this particular form (or anywhere on the page) is unique, we could use that.

Comment: No, that is the problem. I think I had to rewrite the code and make another implementation to handle this task with only one form that have a unique ID.

Comment: Good idea, or even a div wrapper with an ID that you can use as a constant. Then you can start targeting virtually anything.